# Transforming F-dist or long one tail

Tags: data-transformation, standardization, beta-distribution, f-distribution

I have been going through different kaggle datasets recently to apply different techniques I have learned. I have seen loads of articles related to preprocessing your features with normalization or standardization. Generally the rule I have been following is that if the underline distribution is normal, or approx normal, then apply standardization otherwise normalization. This has worked relatively well, but with this current dataset I am experiencing several features that follow the F-dist or long 1 sided tail (also looks like the beta distribution shape). What are some techniques that are utilized to transform/handle these types of features before feeding into a logistic regression model?

I have tried searching, blindly, for some information on handling these distributions but to no avail. Any help pointing me in the right direction of what to search for would be very much appreciated!

[image: Distribution]

Comment: "Box-Cox" is the first keyword to use in your search.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the point in the right direction!

Comment: If the distribution were actually triangular as the histogram seems to hint, and if  upper and lower bound on its support were known (call them $x_m$ and $x_l$ say), then $\Phi^{-1}(1-(1-\frac{x-x_l}{x_m-x_l})^2)$ would be standard Gaussian. Among power transformations (like the Box-Cox family is, up to scale and location), the 0.6 power is approximately symmetrizing. That is, $x^* = (x-x_l)^{3/5}$ should be roughly symmetric (where $x_l$ is again the lower boundary of the support). This is not so far from the (shifted) square root that it might be feasible as a choice.

Comment: A power around 0.57-ish may do better than 0.5 or 0.6 but would be harder to interpret than a square root; since you don't actually need it to be either normal or symmetric, the square root should be fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what leads you to mention the F distribution in the title? The drawing doesn't look like an F to me and the tail looks  pretty short. Could you maybe show an actual histogram (preferably with more bars)?

Comment: I am sorry for the late response, your answer is a bit too complex for me to understand still. I have started doing research on power transformations just so I can get some context/idea of what you are talking about. I know that the F dist is continuous in the + while my distribution is discrete, I wanted to illustrate that the overall shape of the distribution is similar with a early peak and a long right tail. @Glen_b please let me know if there are any other concepts I should also research to get a better idea of the problem and if the solution im proposing is even necessary?

Comment: If you have a discrete distribution, transformation won't do much. You're moving a bunch of different sized spikes around, not changing their heights. (What mentioning F did was convey the impression it was continuous.)  ... a number of posts on site discuss the problems with transformation of discrete variables with most of the probability in only a few places